# Recursive Binary Search and Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, binary-search

I am reading in a list with unsorted numbers:

```
5 24 27 23 8 6 19
```

I got the binary search down, but I don't know how to use it to insert values in order. I need to change my insertInOrder method, so that the numbers are in ascending order. My method right now doesn't really do anything except print the list backwards.

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int cnt, int newVal )
{

    int index = -( bSearch( arr, 0, arr.length-1, newVal)) - 1;
    {
            for ( int i = cnt; i >= index+1 ; --i)
            {
                    arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            }

        arr[index] = newVal;
    }

}

public static int bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
 {
    int mid = lo+(lo + hi)/2;

    if (lo <= hi) 
        return -(lo+1); 
    else if (a[mid] == key) 
        return mid;
    else if (a[mid] < key)
        return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
    else 
        return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
 }
```

---

Edit:

```
input: 5 24 27 23 8 6 19
current output: 19 6 8 23 27 24 5
expected output: 5 6 8 19 23 24 27
```

Comment: Post `input`, `current output`, and `expected output`, each clearly labeled as such. I think your input is `5 24 27 23 8 6 19`...? Not sure though...

Comment: a binary search only works on sorted arrays, since it relies on the order of the items to know in which half to search ...

Comment: Just as a note, Java's [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class already has a <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[], int)" title="Java's binary search">binary search</a>

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use just use the `Arrays` class `sort` method?

```
    int myNumbers[] = {24,7,13,18,29};
    Arrays.sort(myNumbers);
    for(int i : myNumbers) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

See docs [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm).

Comment: Was going to suggest this, then computer crashed. :/

This is definitely the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: It's part of a project so I need to implement my bSearch in the insertInOrder method.